# Access Denied from aweber redirect

Tags: redirect, access-denied, aweber

One of my pages in my domain is set up as a redirect from aweber, so when I confirm on the link on an email optin from aweber it redirects to this page MyPage.html and includes a welcome message with the name I signed up with.

Now granted I am not sure if this is something to do with aweber set up for redirect although it's very easy to do (basically paste the URL in settings you want to redirect to) and I have double/triple checked it. I also contacted aweber support who said it can be the javascript for personalisation embedded in the Head section of the redirect page that can cause this error. I have removed this code and can confirm it is not the javascript or redirect causing it hence my appearance here.

I also have another portion of the site using this redirect and personalisation and it works fine.

Now when I click on the link in my email from aweber it gives me this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /mypage.html on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an >ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And the redirect URL is below so I can see it is redirecting with my details ok but failing to give me access to the page.

> mysite.com/mypage.html?email=myemail%40yahoo.co.uk&from=myemail%40yahoo.co.uk&meta_adtracking=my_web_site&meta_message=1001&name=MyName&unit=MyAweberListName&add_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MySite.com%2FthankyouPage.html&add_notes=xx.xx.xx.xxx

All my pages have access permission 644 and the page is a copy of one of my other pages, which works fine, I've not added anything, changed anything, only removed text lines and graphics.

I just also tried remaking the landing page and it failed once more. Funnily enough though when I manually type the page into the URL bar up it comes; this worked before with the original page as well!

This works:

> mysite.com/mypage.html

This [redirect] doesn't and gives the error described above

> mysite.com/mypage.html?email=myemail%40yahoo.co.uk&from=myemail%40yahoo.co.uk&meta_adtracking=my_web_site&meta_message=1001&name=MyName&unit=MyAweberListName&add_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MySite.com%2FthankyouPage.html&add_notes=xx.xx.xx.xxx

Any ideas on getting to the bottom of this would be greatly appreciated.

Host is hostgator

Comment: How do you redirect from aweber without being aweber?

Comment: @ebyrob - Click on link in email optin from aweber?

Comment: I don't click on links in emails...  My point was that "redirecting from" generally requires you to be the recipient of an HTTP request.  (You could also be on a proxy of some kind, but you mention nothing of the sort so it's pretty hard to figure out what you're talking about in paragraph 1.)  When you get `You don't have permission to access /mypage.html on this server.` it's pretty clear your own server is rejecting you or you're going to the right page/wrong server.  A sniffer session (I'd use fiddler) would tell you exactly what server(s) are/aren't involved.

Comment: PS - If you have a 500 on your own server your server logs should be absolutely screaming about it.